# React Fabric UI Nav with nested links make always collapsible

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

Is there is any way to make Nav with nested links make always collapsible?
Right now I am having a huge array of `INavLinkGroup[]` with big amount of nested links so it looks bad when page is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a solution
In INavLinkGroup there is property: `collapseByDefault?: boolean;`